# issues with installing devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

here's my current user schema:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name :string
#  last_name  :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchkick word_start: [:user]
    has_many :posts
    validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```

these are the steps I'm able to go through before the problem rears its head:

```
rails generate devise:install     
rails generate devise user        
rake db:migrate
```

once i try to migrate it, this is what comes up:

```
== 20160707230510 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "email" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/aa/Documents/railsy/basicProject/db/migrate/20160707230510_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/aa/Documents/railsy/basicProject/db/migrate/20160707230510_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "email" of relation "users" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/Users/aa/Documents/railsy/basicProject/db/migrate/20160707230510_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/aa/Documents/railsy/basicProject/db/migrate/20160707230510_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "email" of relation "users" already exists
/Users/aa/Documents/railsy/basicProject/db/migrate/20160707230510_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/Users/aa/Documents/railsy/basicProject/db/migrate/20160707230510_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

as you can tell from my earlier user schema, there is no email column there. so ... why does this error come up?

**EDIT - should have posted devise migration file - the one that doesn't work **

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip


      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

when i run `rails g devise user` ... this is what comes up:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 72318
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160707230510_add_devise_to_users.rb
      insert    app/models/user.rb
       route  devise_for :users
```

Comment: Possibly your scheme is outdated, but on the table in your database if there is a field. You can rename the field email migration `db/migrate/2016xxxxxx_devise_create_users.rb` and run again (`bundle exec rake db:migrate`).

Comment: @kalec, my schema is not outdated. it simply doesn't have the email column. i would know. =)

Comment: @kalelc, my original user schema doesn't have it ... but i just updated my post with the devise migration file that i'm not able to run ... and hence its error ... it lists the email field in that ... but why it screams duplicate befuddles me ...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I had to do was to do `rake db:setup` which recreates the db. Then I ran `rake db:migrate`, and no issues came up this time.

FYI. Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate migration errors on duplicate fields, use t.change as shown below.

```
t.change :email, :string,     :null => false, :default => ""
```

Notice that for t.change to work, you have to specify the type for the field being changed. In the case of the email migration above, the email field was of type string.

You can refer at: [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns)

Comment: I'd rather you comment all the columns that you already have, but was regenerated by devise. If you need to change the datatypes, you could do that in another migration

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 when you ran this line `rails generate devise user`, a migration file was created, and it was called `DeviseCreateUser`. You can check this file in `db/migrate` folder

Comment: @Khanh Pham, apologies, i just updated my question above with devise's migration file ... and as you can see, it contains the :email column that you suggested to run ...

Comment: @KhanhPham, actually not. it doesn't run `DeviseCreateUser` file per se ... will update post in  sec again.

Comment: @KhanhPham, as you can see from the update above, it creates `AddDevisetoUser` and that already has the email column generated from Devise

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 i updated my answer, please check it again

Comment: @KhanhPham, added the line in your answer to `AddDeviseToUser` file, and ran migration again ... same error as in post pops up again ...